# Freeswitch Event Consumer

Tags: lua, freeswitch

Please I need assistance on how to access and manipulate information from the code.
The example is available in from Freeswitch lua API page but i can figure how to make it work. https://developer.signalwire.com/fr...es/Lua-API-Reference/#freeswitcheventconsumer
My scenario is that am trying to make outbound call and to detect CHANNEL_ANSWER event but with the code the channel was completely block even after hangup
I will appreciate your suggestion

con = freeswitch.EventConsumer("all"); --enabled EventConsumer

con = freeswitch.EventConsumer()

con:bind( 'CHANNEL_ANSWER' )

con:bind( 'CHANNEL_EXECUTE_COMPLETE' )

con:bind( 'CHANNEL_HANGUP' )

while session:ready() do

event = con:pop(1)

if event then freeswitch.consoleLog("info", "#####Event####### = " .. event )

end

end